# Python Django - Pass initial value into bound form

Tags: django

I'm new to Python Django and I'm trying to set up a bound form with three fields where one field (which will be read only) takes an initial value and displays it on the form; the other two fields will be populated by the user when they completes the form.  But when I try to submit the form, the form.is_valid returns false, and I'm not sure what I did wrong.  Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Here's the code:

views.py

```
class AddKeyAccompView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'AddKeyAccomp.html'

    def get(self, request, Program):
        username = request.user.username
        form = AddKeyAccompForm(request, Program=Program)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form
                                                    ,'title':'Add New Key Accomplishment'
                                                    ,'User': username
                                                    })

    def post(self, request, Program):
        username = request.user.username
        form = AddKeyAccompForm(request.POST, Program=Program)
        if form.is_valid():
            Name = form.cleaned_data['Name']
            Description = form.cleaned_data['Description']
            form.save()
            form = AddKeyAccompForm(request, Program=Program)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ModInit', args=[Program]))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('invalid form')
        args = {'form': form
                ,'title':'Add New Key Accomplishment'
                ,'User': username
                ,'Name': Name
                ,'Desc': Description
                ,'Program': Program
                }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

forms.py

```
class AddKeyAccompForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.program = kwargs.pop('Program')
        super(AddKeyAccompForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Program'].initial = self.program

    class Meta:
        model = Key_Accomplishments
        fields = ('Name', 'Description', 'Program',)
        widgets = {
                    'Name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':True, 'class':'form-control'})
                    ,'Description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'required': True, 'class':'form-control'})
                    ,'Program': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly', 'class':'form-control'})
        }
```

html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>New Key Accomplishment</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                <center>{{ title }}</center>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="offset-3 col-md-6">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-left:10%;">
                {% for field in form %}
                <label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                {{ field }}
                <br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="btn" style="padding-left: 10%;">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've changed the signature of the form's init method to accept `request`. Don't do that. You're not using it anyway.

Comment: But you don't need to pass Program in like that either; why not just `form = AddKeyAccompForm(initial={'Program': Program})`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I had that before and I get the following error:  KeyError at /AddKeyAccomp/Cybersecurity Program
'Program'.  the error seems to come from form = AddKeyAccompForm(initial={'Program': Program}) and  self.program = kwargs.pop('Program')

Comment: Yes as I said you do not need to do anything with kwargs. Remove that `__init__` method altogether.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Got this to work now.